# Из upstart в systemd

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, systemd

У меня Ubuntu 18.04 не поддерживает upstart, использует systemd.

Как мне создать сервис с помощью systemd, на основе этого файла file.conf?

```
#!upstart
start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

script
        while true;
        do
            sudo -u deploy bash -c "/usr/bin/php /symfony/bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -w compare -m 1 --env=prod"

        if [ $?  -ne 0 ]; then
            stop; exit 1;
        fi

        done
end script
```

Comment: `sudo -u deploy bash -c` ну очень плохо.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Unit]
Description=My cool PHP app

[Service]
User=deploy
WorkingDirectory=/symfony/bin
Environment="OPTS=rabbitmq:consumer -w compare -m 1 --env=prod"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "php console $OPTS"

StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=php-console

RestartSec=5
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html